# CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation hole creation

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm using CGAL library to triangulate a polygon. The library seems to triangulate the holes as well which is fine by me but I'd like to draw the mesh without them. I am not able to find if there is someway to identify which faces belong to the hole. Does anyone know if there is or is not an existing way to find the info I seek?

Below are some of the functions I am using.

```
std::list<Point> seeds;
CGAL::Delaunay_mesher_2 mesh(cdt);
mesh.set_criteria(Criteria(0.125, 20);
mesh.set_seeds(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
mesh.refine_mesh();
CGAL::lloyd_optimize_mesh_2(cdt, CGAL::parameters::max_iteration_number = 10);
```

I thought that I might be able to find them with the marked flag but it does not seem to be the case.

I add the hole as a seed. When I iterate the faces and check fit->is_marked(), they all are marked.

`for(CDT::Finite_faces_iterator fit = cdt.finite_faces_begin(), end = cdt.finite_faces_end(); fit != end; ++fit)`

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2polygon_triangulation_8cpp-example.html) where the triangles in the domain get marked.

[The same example](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2polygon_triangulation_8cpp-example.html) In the master branch on github.com uses the function to mark the domain which has become an official function that is it is now in the  `CGAL` namespace.

Comment: A real shame if that really is the built in way. Looks way more difficult than it needs to be. Got to use custom stuff then.